# CSS heart throbbing inside a button next to text

Tags: html, css

I have a donate button that is in a navbar that I need to add a throbbing heart next to the word Donate. I created the heart using CSS but every time I try to put it next to the word Donate, the heart is either way off from the button, not in the correct shape or the button splits. How can I get the throbbing heart inside the button next to the left of "Donate"?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```css
.donate-btn>a {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ca0e17;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.box-heartbeat {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: heartbeat 0.8s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 30px;
}

.box-heartbeat:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  top: -50%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.box-heartbeat:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  right: -50%;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="donate-btn">
      <a href="{!! route('marketing.donate') !!}">{{ trans('layouts/master/navigation.donate') }}</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Okay, so I figured a solution. If you know of something better, I would still love to know! I ended up adding more padding to the left of the button to widen it, added position absolute to the box-heartbeat and positioned using top and left. I actually had another button that I used for mobile and that had to be wrapped with a container with position relative to get the heart to stay in position for different screen sizes:

```
.donate-btn>a { text-align: center; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; background-color: #ca0e17; padding: 5px 10px 5px 35px; border-radius: 5px; margin-left: 20px; }

.box-heartbeat {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  animation: heartbeat 0.9s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Please revise to show just _one_ attempt, and put it in a demo snippet using the editor.

Comment: check this: https://css-loaders.com/pulsing/#l3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.donate-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.donate-btn > a {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ca0e17;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box-heartbeat {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: heartbeat 0.9s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box-heartbeat:before,
.box-heartbeat:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.box-heartbeat:before {
  top: -50%;
}

.box-heartbeat:after {
  right: -50%;
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.05);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="donate-btn">
      <div class="box-heartbeat"></div>
      <a href="{!! route('marketing.donate') !!}">{{ trans('layouts/master/navigation.donate') }}</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @RyanM if this is helpful or this is like you want you can accept my answer thanks

Comment: Thanks! That also worked! I always like to see different ways of doing things and getting new ideas. A little bit cleaner with the before and after. Much appreciated!